# Generators of a maximal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
It is well-known that $I$ is of the following form $\langle x-\alpha, y-\beta \rangle$, where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

Assume that $\langle u,v \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

> Is it true that $u=g(x), v=g(y)$, where $g$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

For example, $u= x+y^3, v=y$ generate the maximal ideal $\langle x,y \rangle$
(here $\alpha=\beta=0$ and $u,v$ are images of the automorphism $g: (x,y) \mapsto (x+y^3,y)$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: $\Bbb{C}$ is a field so its only maximal ideal is $\langle 0\rangle$. Something is missing

Comment: @marwalix, oh, thanks. I meant that $\langle u,v \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$..

Comment: I thought so but didn’t dare to edit

Comment: @marwalix, thank you.. Please, do you think that my question has a positive answer?

Comment: $(x,y)\to (x-\alpha,y-\beta)$ seems to me to be an automorphism. We have $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle x-\alpha,y-\beta\rangle$ for some $\alpha,\beta$

Comment: Please, I meant given general $u,v$ that generate a maximal ideal, namely $\langle u,v \rangle= \langle x-c,y-d \rangle$, for some $c,d \in \mathbb{C}$, is it true that $u=g(x),v=g(y)$ for some automorphism $g$.

Comment: The purpose of my example was to hint that my question has a positive answer (since at least the example satisfies the claim in my question with $\alpha=\beta=0$ or with your automorphism).

Comment: @user237522 In the example you gave, how do you define $g$?

Comment: @pigeon, $g(x)=x+y^3$, $g(y)=y$.

Comment: @user237522 that's not a well defined polynomial. If you set $g(X)=X+y^3$ then $g(y)=y+y^3$. You just replace the  variable in the expression.

Comment: You should instead consider $f(x,y)=x+y^3$ and $g(x,y)=y$.

Comment: @pigeon, did you mean that $u=x+y^3, v=y+y^3$ generate a maximal ideal? In this case (but it does not seem that such $u,v$ generate a maximal ideal) my claim is wrong, since there is no automorphism $g$ such that $u=g(x),v=g(y)$.

Comment: Perhaps I should have added that $u,v$ have a non-zero scalar Jacobian? But apriori we do not know this. If my claim is true, then we obtain that $u,v$, as an automorphic pair, have a non-zero scalar Jacobian.

Comment: @pigeon $g : \Bbb{C}[x,y]\to\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ is the unique map of $\Bbb{C}$-algebras satisfying $g(x) = x + y^3$ and $g(y) = y.$ If you let $f(x,y) = x + y^3,$ then $g(p(x,y)) := p(f(x,y),y)$ for any $p\in\Bbb{C}[x,y].$

Comment: @Stahl, please, could you explain what you meant in your comment? Is my question has a positive answer?

Comment: It seems to me that my question has a positive answer, and I try to prove it in the last comments after the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\langle u,v\rangle$ a maximal ideal of $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]$.

We have

$$\begin{align}
u(x,y)&=p(x,y)(x-\alpha)+q(x,y)(y-\beta)\\
v(x,y)&=r(x,y)(x-\alpha)+r(x,y)(y-\beta)
\end{align}$$

Can this transformation be an automorphism of $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]$ as a vector space (it is not an automorphism of algebra)

The question is what is the value of the determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}
p(x,y) & q(x,y)\\
r(x,y) & s(x,y)
\end{vmatrix}$$

More specifically can it be $0$ if the ideal is maximal.

Let’s look at an example

Consider $p(x,y)=x=q(x,y)$ and $r(x,y)=y=s(x,y)$ we have:

$$\begin{align}
u(x,y)&=x^2+xy-(\alpha+\beta)x\\
v(x,y)&=y^2+xy-(\alpha+\beta)y
\end{align}$$

It seems to me that this is not an automorphism and that the ideal is the same

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not sure I fully understood your answer; in particular, why the two elements $x+xy-(\alpha+\beta)x$, $y^2+xy-(\alpha+\beta)y$ are another pair of generators of $I$? (Generally: Given $I=\langle u,v \rangle$, not necessarily a maximal ideal, how do we know if two elements $A,B \in I$ generate $I$? we should have $u=pA+qB$ and $v=rA+sB$).

Comment: Even in the special case $\alpha=\beta=0$, in which $A=x^2+xy$, $B=y^2+xy$, I do not see why $A,B$ generate $\langle x,y \rangle$, but probably I am missing something. (It is clear that $(x,y) \mapsto (x^2+xy,y^2+xy)$ is not an automorphism).

Comment: Please, for $\alpha=\beta=0$, we have $A=x^2+xy, B=y^2+xy$ for which $I=(x^2+xy, y^2+xy) \subsetneq (x,y)$. $I$ vanishes not only on $(0,0)$ but also on infinitely many $(c,-c)$, $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Using your notations: By assumption $(u,v)=(x-\alpha,y-\beta)$, so your polynomial coefficients $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ must satisfy $ps-qr \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Maybe then it is not difficult to conclude that $u=g(x),v=g(y)$, though I am not sure what $g$ is, except that $p,q,r,s$ should be involved.

Comment: For convenience, $ps-qr=1$. Then we have $x-\alpha=su-qv$ and $y-\beta=-ru+pv$. Then $x=su-qv+\alpha$ and $y=-ru+pv+\beta$., but I do not know how to continue, namely, how to find an automorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $u=g(x)$ and $v=g(y)$. Maybe (I'm guessing) $g(x)=sx-qy+\alpha, g(y)=-rx+py+\beta$, but actually the Jacobian of this $g$ seems to be different from a nonzero scalar, so this definition does not work.